# Meteor.find multiple values in an array

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query

I am using auto schema to define an array field. I need to find documents where multiple specific values are contained in that array. I know I can use the `$in:` operator while `$in:` can only match either one of the value in the first array against the second array while I would need to match any record that have all value in the first array. How I can achieve this?

Schema Definition

```
Demands = new Mongo.Collection("demands");

var demandschema = new SimpleSchema({
  ability: {type:array},
  language: {type: array}});

Demands.attachSchema(demandschema);
```

Contents Definition

```
DemandsSet=[
  {ability: ["laser eye", "rocky skin", "fly"], language: ["english", "latin", "hindu"]},
  {ability: ["sky-high jump", "rocky skin", "fly"], language: ["english", "latin", "japanese"]},
  {ability: ["rocky skin", "sky-high jump"], language: ["english", "latin", "russian"]}
];
```

Target Set

```
var TargetAbility = ["rocky skin", "fly"];
var TargetLanguage = ["english", "hindu"];
```

When I do a `$in` operation

```
Demands.find({ $and: [
  { ability: { $in: TargetAbility }}, 
  { language: { $in: TargetLanguage }}
]}).fetch();
```

I will return me with all records, while it is not correct, how can I perform such a find operation?

Comment: At first your code is not valid at all… TargetAbility and TargetLanguage are supposed to be arrays, while the first argument in the find method must be an object. Content definition overrides the Collection object and is confounding objects with arrays Please fix before or people will only reply regarding the syntax instead of the problem itself.

Comment: Agreed his syntax is completely dorked, didn't have the patience to edit it.

Comment: Well sorry about the syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$in:` is not going to work for you because it looks for *any* match when comparing two arrays, not that *all* elements of one array must be present in the other.

You can write complete javascript functions to execute the required comparisons inside the mongodb query. See [$where:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

For example:

```
Demands.find({$where:
  "this.ability.indexOf(TargetAbility[0])   > -1 &&
   this.ability.indexOf(TargetAbility[1])   > -1 &&
   this.language.indexOf(TargetLanguage[0]) > -1 &&
   this.language.indexOf(TargetLanguage[1]) > -1" });
```

If your candidates have other than 2 entries each then you can write a more general form of this of course.

Note that Meteor apparently [does not support the function() form](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/ErgCC4g_bB0) of `$where:` but that restriction may be dated.

Also note that `$where:` cannot take advantage of indexes so performance may not be suitable for large collections.

Comment: Greatest thx for your help and advice.  That saves my date.  In that case,  I will use a lot of boolean fields instead so as to speed up the query. Though it may taken extra effort on the ui side,   i think it worth the time.